# Activity Diagram, is this a acceptable activity Diagram?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I'm just starting to learn about UML and now learning Activity diagram. I was wondering if this would be acceptable as a activity diagram for the program? If not how could I improve?

It's a simple C# console program and works like this:

Starting, the user will receive a bunch of animals. Then from a main menu choose a task/option to do. Some of the menu options also requires user to choose one of animals (to preform task with). After the task is done user will be returned to the menu to choose something else until the user chooses to quit.

[image]

Comment: The answer would be: no. You do have a clear dedlock. First try to figure out yourself why.

Comment: @qwerty_so Sorry but what is a deadlock?

Comment: It's a blocking state that does not allow to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Your AD isn't too bad. Just a few errors:

- `Choose what animal` has three incomming control flows. However, only one of them will present a token since only one of the actions above is possible to be chosen. That's where the deadlock is. You fix that simply by first using a MergeNode (like you did at the bottom) right before that action.
- The second flaw is with the labels you placed along the control flows. That would just be names. But actually you want them to be guards. That is the let pass a token only if the condition inside is fulfilled. Here the fix is to use brackets like `[Quit chosen]` to make them guards.

Comment: Thank you very much! was searching a long time yesterday on google and youtube and honestly could not find a good explanation or help. @qwerty_so